# Android Bottom Sheet Peek Height get trimmed after Search View inside it get clicked

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

So, I have a layout, which becomes my `BottomSheet` view. **Everything going great**, and its `peekHeight` matches my xml. Like below gif:

[image]

Until I decided to type (or even just click) in the `SearchView` inside it.

When the app first run, before the `SearchView`'s TextBox doesn't get focused, it's no problem (still neat). But after it get focused, then suddenly the bottom sheet `peekHeight` get trimmed.

[image]

Idk what caused this, since basically there's no setup done programatically. I even tried to reset the `peekHeight` programmatically each time I finish typing in the `SearchView`, but no luck.

So far my workaround is to add some DP to the `peekHeight` right in the XML. It should be `80dp`, but I declare it `100dp` right from the XML (GIFs are without some addtional DPs).

It gets ugly on the app first run, but after I click the `SearchView`, then it's all good, since the extra height get trimmed, anyway.

This is my bottom navigation xml. (Used with `<include layout=".."/>` on the main xml)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bssf_cl_bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bssf_iv_search_by_algolia"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#80FFFFFF"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_quarter"
    android:src="@drawable/search_by_algolia"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bssf_sv_search_box" />

<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/bssf_sv_search_box"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bssf_iv_show_filter_button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bssf_iv_search_by_algolia"
    app:queryHint="Search" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bssf_iv_show_filter_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_single"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_filter_list_white_24dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bssf_iv_search_by_algolia" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bssf_tv_distance_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_single"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_single"
    android:text="Any Distance"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bssf_iv_show_filter_button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bssf_tv_warning_location_not_turned_on"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_single"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_single"
    android:drawablePadding="2dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_warning_accent_16dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:text="Location is turned off. Tap to turn on"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_small"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/bssf_tv_distance_label"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/bssf_sb_distance"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_single"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_single"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_half"
    android:max="25"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bssf_tv_distance_label" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bssf_tv_price_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_single"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_single"
    android:text="Any Price"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bssf_sb_distance" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/bssf_sb_price"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_half"
    android:max="9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bssf_sb_distance"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/bssf_sb_distance"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bssf_tv_price_label" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bssf_tv_appetizer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_half"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_single"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_single"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_half"
    android:text="Appetizer / Snack"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bssf_tv_main_course"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bssf_sb_price" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bssf_tv_main_course"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_single"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_half"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_half"
    android:text="Main Course"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/bssf_tv_appetizer"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bssf_tv_appetizer" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bssf_tv_dessert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_single"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_half"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_single"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_single"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_half"
    android:text="Dessert"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bssf_tv_beverage"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bssf_tv_appetizer" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bssf_tv_beverage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_half"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_half"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_half"
    android:text="Beverage"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/bssf_tv_dessert"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bssf_tv_other"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bssf_tv_dessert" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bssf_tv_other"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_single"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_half"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_half"
    android:text="Other"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/bssf_tv_dessert"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bssf_tv_beverage" />
```

Any one knows how to resolve this? Thanks

> P.S. If anyone doesn't notice the difference, note that on the first
>   gif, there's a grey line under the `SearchView`, which is still visible
>   before / after collapse / expand. But on the second gif, after i click
>   the `SearchView`, there's no grey line anymore (weirdly got trimmed)

P.S.S. Oh and, maybe this detail is related, but if I try to show a `Snackbar`, regardless the state of the bottom sheet (expanded or collapsed), the sheet will jump to the top, leaving a grey area (from the background), between the bottom sheet and the `Snackbar` at the bottom of the screen. Even before the `SearchView` get clicked. And after the `Snackbar` event, occurrence on gif 2 happened (even if `SearchView` hasn't been clicked yet). Like below gif:

[image]

Comment: For the snackbar event: 
Try using layout_gravity="bottom" on the root (ConstraintLayout) of the bottom sheet content.